# Center Angular modal ui

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am playing with angular modal ui dialog. I wonder what is the way to center it ? I find a similar question:
[Twitter Bootstrap - Center Modal Dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18691071/twitter-bootstrap-center-modal-dialog)

but was unable to make it work as I am rather new to angular. Here is a simplified version of the plunker for modal dialog from the angular ui components page:

http://plnkr.co/edit/M35rpChHYThHLk17g9zU?p=preview

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h3>I'm a modal!</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            test
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="ok()">OK</button>
            <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
        </div>
    </script>

    <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open()">Open me!</button>
```

js:

```
angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap']);
var ModalDemoCtrl = function ($scope, $modal) {

  $scope.open = function () {

    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
      templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
      controller: ModalInstanceCtrl
    });

  };
};


var ModalInstanceCtrl = function ($scope, $modalInstance) {

  $scope.ok = function () {
    $modalInstance.close("ok");
  };

  $scope.cancel = function () {
    $modalInstance.dismiss("cancel");
  };
};
```

My idea is to take the dimensions of the page dynamically when the modal is open and resize and center it, but I am not sure how can I do that as I am rather new to angularjs. Any help with working example will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25160044/900284

Answer (score 29):

You can specify the style class for the modal window by using `windowClass` attribute while creating `modalInstance`

```
var modalInstance = $modal.open({
      templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
      controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
      windowClass: 'center-modal'
    });
```

then in your css you can specify the definition for .center-modal like,

```
.center-modal {
    position: fixed;
    top: 10%;
    left: 18.5%;
    z-index: 1050;
    width: 80%;
    height: 80%;
    margin-left: -10%;
}
```

or specify anything based on your needs

Comment: The sample css will indeed relocate the modal dialog, but breaks the click-outside-dialog-to-close behavior by resizing/relocating the modal wrapper around the dialog as well. Targeting .modal-dialog, as described in http://stackoverflow.com/a/21312755, will avoid this issue.

Comment: @M22an: Is there a way to dynamically change the "windowClass" while the modal is open?

Comment: @me_digvijay, maybe you can try using jQuery if you want to alter the styles.

Answer (score 0):

[This approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35693218/angularjs-ui-bootstrap-how-to-vertical-center-modal-component#answer-35693444) works with any modal size.

```
.modal {
  text-align: center;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) { 
  .modal:before {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    content: " ";
    height: 100%;
  }
}

.modal-dialog {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

The original answer has an example with Plunker.