# Angularjs ui bootstrap: how to vertical center modal component?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

Recently I am learning angularjs. I have used bootstrap before. With jquery, I can easily change the position of the modal component position to make it vertical align. Now with angularjs, it seems not very easy to do that. Here is a plunker link of ui bootstrap modal, Does anyone know how to make it vertical align?

[ui bootstrap modal component](http://plnkr.co/edit/TvLQkPh0cs4McxfLpE9u?p=preview)

1.index.html

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html ng-app="ui.bootstrap.demo">
    <head>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular-animate.js"></script>
        <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-1.2.1.js"></script>
        <script src="example.js"></script>
        <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div ng-controller="ModalDemoCtrl">
            <script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h3 class="modal-title">I'm a modal!</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    This is modal body
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="ok()">OK</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-warning" type="button" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
                </div>
            </script>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open()">Open me!</button>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

2.example.js

```
    angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap']);
    angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('ModalDemoCtrl', function($scope, $uibModal, $log) {

        $scope.items = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'];

        $scope.animationsEnabled = true;

        $scope.open = function(size) {

            var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
                animation: $scope.animationsEnabled,
                templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
                controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
                size: size,
                resolve: {
                    items: function() {
                        return $scope.items;
                    }
                }
            });
        };
    });

    angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('ModalInstanceCtrl',   function($scope, $uibModalInstance, items) {
        $scope.ok = function() {
            $uibModalInstance.close($scope.selected.item);
        };

        $scope.cancel = function() {
            $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
        };
    });
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, you can acheive the vertical center alignment just by using CSS. Add following CSS:

```
.modal {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0!important;
}

.modal::before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: -4px;
}

.modal-dialog {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

I have setup a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/pT3NzGvqiRjbQSzIoNph?p=preview) forked from yours to make a demonstration.

You can find following links Helpful

1. [Bootstrap 3 modal vertical position center](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18422223/bootstrap-3-modal-vertical-position-center)
2. [Codepen Emaple](http://codepen.io/dimbslmh/full/mKfCc)

Hope this helps. Cheers !!

Comment: Thanks, this solves my problem, I haven't thought it could be solved in pure css.

Answer (score 2):

The above solutions will apply to all the modals. If you want to apply to selective modals then follow the below given solution.

The CSS uses `.class-a.class-b` and `.class-a .class-b` selector and need to set option `windowClass`.

```
.center-modal.modal {
  text-align: center;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) { 
  .center-modal.modal:before {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    content: " ";
    height: 100%;
  }
}

.center-modal .modal-dialog {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
    templateUrl: 'modules/users/client/views/authentication/login.client.view.html',
    windowClass: "center-modal"
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `windowTopClass` property in the object argument for `open` method.

https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

```
$uibModal.open({
  ...
  ...
  windowTopClass: "modal-center-override"
});
```

with the respective CSS class override

```
.modal-center-override {
  top: 50% !important;
  transform: translateY(-50%) !important;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%) !important;
  -moz-transform: translateY(-50%) !important;
  -o-transform: translateY(-50%) !important;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Some Time modal-dialog-centered class not working in ng-template.

In Angular is simple way of modal vertical center .
just use centered: true in side open function when you call modalService.open.

**like bellow**

import NgbModal :

```
import { NgbModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
constructor(
  private modalService: NgbModal
 ) {}
this.modalService.open(content, { centered: true });
```

Use this i hope it work